# How to strip invalid UTF-8 characters from a string?

Tags: character-encoding

### TL;DR:

I have a string with characters that are unencodable in UTF-8, and I
need to remove these characters before writing the string to a file.

For instance, the following snippet creates a file that contains an
invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. I would like this sequence to just not be
present in the output file.

```
(let ((coding-system-for-write 'utf-8))
  (write-region "This is invalid: \x19008e" nil "~/outputfile"))
```

By checking this character with `describe-char`, I can see Emacs *knows* it is not encodable through UTF-8. So there must be a way to detect these characters and remove them.

---

### The Background

I have an emacs-lisp script which converts docstrings to html files,
which must be entirely in UTF-8. The following snippet shows
essentially what I've been doing so far.

```el
(with-temp-file output-file
  (insert symbol-name "\n" symbol-documentation)
  (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'no-conversion))
```

Where `symbol-documentation` is the string returned by
`describe-variable` (the content of the Help buffer).

This seemed to work fine at first, but now I've realised this was
causing some files to contain byte-sequences that are not valid UTF-8.
Some perpetrators are `tibetan-precomposition-rule-alist`,
`language-info-alist`, `composition-function-table`. By manually
checking their documentation, I can see my Emacs indeed fails to
comprehend part of the content.

**Q: How can I ensure only valid UTF-8 byte sequences are written to the output file?**
I'm perfectly fine with skipping these invalid sequences entirely
(instead of trying to understand them). I just want to make sure the
output file is valid.

I tried changing `no-conversion` to `utf-8`, but then my script gets
interrupted by a `Select coding system:` prompt, and the problem
still happens.

Comment: Maybe write with `utf-16` (this will work), and convert in to `utf-8` with some command-line tool?

Comment: @abo-abo Good idea, I'll try to look for a tool for that.

Comment: How large is the output and how often do you need to produce it? I've written once a UTF-8 encoder in Emacs Lisp, but if this has to be fast, you'd probably do better using some existing library, like `iconv` for example.

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, it kinda needs to be fast. I'm looking into iconv now.

Comment: `iconv -cf UTF-8 -t UTF-8 ./outputfile > ./converted` should do it, I believe.

Comment: Using `utf-8` coding system is The Right Thing.  Using `no-conversion` is just an admission that you don't know what you're doing (because, really, there is always some conversion going on).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the same mechanism that `describe-char` [uses](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/descr-text.el?id=f4a6345114b02fb725192aa548f2e84096fbaae6#n630) to identify whether a character is encodable using `utf-8` i.e. use `encode-coding-char`. From the documentation

> Encode CHAR by CODING-SYSTEM and return the resulting string. If
>   CODING-SYSTEM can't safely encode CHAR, return nil. The 3rd optional
>   argument CHARSET, if non-nil, is a charset preferred on encoding.

```el
(defun my-remove-unencodeable-chars (string)
  (string-join
   (delq nil (mapcar (lambda (ch) (encode-coding-char ch 'utf-8 'unicode))
               string))))
```

Comment: Thanks, `encode-coding-char` is just what I was looking for. I've made small edit to the code (mapcar can work directly on strings, no need to split first).

Answer (score 1):

You want to let-bind `coding-system-for-write` to `utf-8` around the call to `write-region`.  This won't prompt you, even if there are characters that can't be encoded.