# fix buffer invalid UTF-8 encoding characters by query/replace

Tags: character-encoding, query-replace

When I copy text from web pages, there are some special characters like ', - etc (not UTF-8 encoding). As you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

I checked out some similar questions in this site:

- [X] [How to strip invalid UTF-8 characters from a string?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/how-to-strip-invalid-utf-8-characters-from-a-string)
- [X] [How to fix latin character (e.g. ç, é) incorrectly displayed in emacs ess-buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/how-to-fix-latin-character-e-g-%c3%a7-%c3%a9-incorrectly-displayed-in-emacs-ess-buffer)
- [X] [How encode to UTF-8 content of buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37459/how-encode-to-utf-8-content-of-buffer)
- [X] [Character encoding when copying some text from somewhere to Emacs and saving to a file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/372/character-encoding-when-copying-some-text-from-somewhere-to-emacs-and-saving-to)

But can't find what I want.
I want to do query/replace all invalid UTF-8 encoding characters in buffer just like `[M-%]` in Emacs.

Comment: This is an interesting question, especially in a sense that I don't know whether it is possible to find a regular expression that matches all bytes that constitute invalid UTF-8 encoding. What would be relatively easy though is to write a function that parses text in the buffer as UTF-8 and prompts for replacement when it encounters something it cannot parse. I think, I had a UTF-8 parser in Elisp somewhere, maybe I'll try to write something like this towards the end of the day.